# How to redirect to url without parameters in the url

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-routing

I need to redirect to / and I need to pass some parameters. I want that that parameters doesn't appear in the url. Suppose to be in this link:

```
./Employees
```

and I need to return in `./` so I do:

```
this.route.navigate(['./'], { queryParams: { params: 3 }, skipLocationChange: true });
```

The problem is that redirect works but the Url that I read is not ./ but `./Employees`. I want that the URL is not ./Employees but became ./. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your default path in your route file is redirected to employees.
for e.g.

```
            {
                path: '/',
                pathMatch: 'full',
                redirectTo: 'Employees'
            },
```

You need to remove the redirectTo in that and add a component where you want to redirect.

```
               {
                    path: '/',
                    component: yourComponent,
                },
```

Comment: I don't have use your solution but I resolve my problem add to my code in the examplke this.location.replaceState("/");